# How to have Netbeans IDE remember which functions are minimized after closing?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I have some huge functions that I like to have minimized to make it easier to read my code, but when I close Netbeans it doesn't keep the same functions minimized.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you enter this line of code;

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Some description here.....">
```

above the code you wish to hide, and after it this;

```
// </editor-fold>
```

it should always be closed when opening the file. This is default code from creating a servlet in netbeans.